# Skype probably breaking Windows Internet connectivity

Tags: windows, skype, connectivity

I have three cases when using Skype on Windows is most probably the cause of Internet connectivity interruption on the computers in question.

Two of computers affected run Windows 7 Eng 64-bit, one runs Windows 8 Eng 64-bit, latest updates installed.

In two cases (one of Windows 7 computers + Windows 8 computer) after using Skype for some time Internet connectivity is broken, namely

1. All local network connectivity isn't affected
2. Traffic that should be
   passed outside local network, doesn't leave the computer (when
   recording traffic on gateway, not a single packet comes from the
   computer in question)
3. "route print" displays normal routing table
   (no duplicate routes/other routing errors)

Uninstalling/Reinstalling Skype in the above cases cured the problem immediately.

The third case (Windows 7): using Skype to generate much traffic (e.g., holding audio/video conference) causes short-time Internet connectivity loss. As in earlier mentioned cases, local connectivity isn't lost, but all outer hosts, when tracert'ed, are displayed as available in single hop, yet they do not respond. In this case the problem heals by itself.

Linux-running computer serves as gateway to Internet (NAT).

Checked and adjusted already: routing, DHCP/DNS settings, firewall rules, malware scanning (nothing found), checking hardware, replacing patchcords/network cards, all for no avail. Switching "UPnP" in Skype off in the latter case made no difference, the first two didn't yet exhibit the mentioned problem again after disabling UPnP.

Skype version used: the latest one, available from Skype.com. The rest of systems running Skype, on Windows or not, do not report similar problems.

**Question**: are there known Skype-inflicted connectivity problems in Windows, and, if yes, what are ways to solve them *reliably*?

Comment: That's amazing - insetad of offering a solution, just downvoting? It's confirmed last Skype version *can* cause connectivity problems on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Skype uses port 80 by default. You could try changing the default port to something else that doesn't already have a service running on it.

Comment: Done as well; that didn't change anything, and the computers in question do not run anything on HTTP/HTTPS standard ports.